# Since my last reinstallation I get a small belle sound each time I click on a site in Firefox

Tags: sound, firefox

Since wiping my computer and reinstalling 20.04 LTS and the rest of necessary programs, each time I click on a site in Firefox I hear a small bell sound and I haven't found any information on this on-line nor in the "preferences" of Firefox.
Is there any way to get rid of this sound ?

Answer (score 0):

It will be Ubuntu System Sounds and not in Firefox settings.

[image]

Press the <kbd>Super</kbd> key and type `Settings`. 
 Go to Sound → Volume Levels and move the slider all the way to the left as shown in the graphic above.

Comment: would this not also disable other perhaps wanted system sounds?

Comment: Thanks but I've already put the "system sounds" slider completely to the left and the little bell / chime sound continues. Since yesterday I've fiddled around a bit and found that when using "Tor Browser" it does not ring the little bell which makes me think that it's Firefox's fault !! This isn't a matter of life and death, it's simply annoying so there's no mad panic simply annoyance and curiosity.